# is there a way to display a particular inline in a new page based on a condition?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I need to display only one inline in a new page based on the condition like if the url has the parameter country_id then i need to display only one inline. Since I cannot make it in one ModelAdmin since the model admin has form validations in it, I used two modelAdmins for the same model. I have a readonly field called get_countries in CorporateConfig(admin which has form validations) and it will display a list of countries. If i click on a country based on that country id i need to display CorporateBrand which is an inline model to CorporateConfig on a new page(remember only that inline needs to be displayed).

```
class CorporateConfigurationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CorporateConfigurationAdminForm
    inlines = [CorporateIncludeBrandAdmin, CorporateExcludeBrandAdmin,
               CorporateBrandsAdmin]
    
    def get_urls(self):
       from django.urls import path
       urls = super(CorporateConfigurationAdmin,self).get_urls()
       filter_url = [
           path('filter_brand/',self.admin_site.admin_view(self.brand_filter), name='brand-filter'),
        ]
       return filter_url + urls

    def brand_filter(self, request, obj=None):
        pass

    def get_countries(self, instance):
        country_list = '<ul style="font-weight: bold;list-style-type:circle;">'
        countries = Country.objects.all()
        print("countries", countries)
        for country in countries:
            url = reverse_lazy('admin:brand-filter')
            print("urls is",url)
            country_list += '<li class="changelist"><a href="{url}?country_id={id}" target="_blank">{country}</a></li>'.format(url=url, country=country.name,id=country.id)
        country_list+='</ul>'
        return mark_safe(country_list)

    get_countries.short_description = 'Country Url'

Clicking on the link above should go to the custom url which is created by get_urls() 

class BrandOrderFilter(CorporateConfiguration):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True


class CorporateInlineBaseAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        country = request.GET.get('country_id')
        qs = super(CorporateInlineBaseAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if country:
            qs = qs.filter(brand__country=country)
        return qs

class CorporateBrandOrderFilterAdmin(CorporateInlineBaseAdmin):
    fields = ('brand', 'order_number',)
    raw_id_fields = ('brand',)
    ordering = ('order_number',)
    model = CorporateBrand

class BrandOrderFilteringAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CorporateBrandOrderFilterAdmin,]
```

Now i can able to filter according to the countries but the fields from the model and validation is done by the form. So I created another admin and without using form i tried to display only that particular inline. unfortunately i am unable to do it. After 11 hours of hardwork im posting it here so that I can get some answers. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this functionality by creating a new form and excluding the fields I needed and in the url I fetched the parameter request.GET.get('country_id'). If there was a country_id I am returning the new form with my new inline in a new page else return the form with all the inlines.